# Callback Basics

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm losing my understanding of parameters in a call back.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
// A route for the home page - will render a view
```

This is using the express library and is a basic home page route.  I'm just confused on how does this actually get the req/res objects?  Does the server itself invoke the function whenever it receives a req/res object on the '/' page ?

I understand what the function does, I just don't know how it actually receives its parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you get those parameters from the server. Whenever Express (i.e. Node.js) receives a request it runs your callback and provides those two parameters.

Think of it like a talk between two persons:

- You: 'Hey Golo, I'm an expert in X. So when anybody asks you about X, please tell me and give me their phone number.'
- Me: 'Okay, fine, I'll do that.'
- (…)
- Me: 'Hey HelloWorld, I now have a request. The contact data are +49 177 …'

*Please tell me and give me their phone number.* is the callback. The phone number is the parameter to the callback.

So, the phone number in this case is the very same thing as your `req` and `res` objects. And I am acting like Node.js / Express in this example, you are the application that is run.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intuitive way to look at it:

`app.get()` is a function that takes 2 parameters, the first is your path taken as a string and the second param is a function. This function will be called back by app.get();

So let's say that you invoke `app.get` like so:

```
app.get('/', function abc(req, res){..})
```

Then, the implementation of `app.get` will be something along the lines of :

```
app.get = function(path, callBackFunction){
   // do some stuff here to get the values of req and res
   callBackFunction(req, res); // calling back the function passed to us with req and res
}
```